# How to clean cut a region from Tiff image?

Tags: image-editing, tiff

I have a big Tiff image where I would like to cut a region. 
I can use Debian Linux 8.1 and OSX 10.8.5 at the moment.

How can you clean cut a small region of the full Tiff image?

Comment: Sorry if my question shows my lack of understanding, but why can't you use a picture editor (such as Photoshop) or similar?

Comment: Cut it and do what with it and the original?  Are you talking about creating a new image from a piece of another image?  Cutting out a region from an image and leaving a hole?  Cropping the image?  Is the cut a rectangular area or some other shape?  Tiff is a standard, popular image format and I would guess that almost any image editor would let you do this as a basic task (well basic depending on exactly what you're trying to do).  What aspect of this is the challenge?  Have you tried to do it with the image editor that came bundled with either OS?  What tools do you have to work with?

Comment: @Dave I am interested about how well those tools manages the edges.

Comment: @fixer1234, the fact you ask 8 questions in your comment is why I'm voting to close! Masi, please edit your question and put in more detail. As it is, (and based upon the 1 answer you've got) it reads as if you are asking how to crop part of an image

Comment: @Masi: your comment to Dave raises still another question.  Cuts are typically simple, clean lines.  You can do other things with the edges (blending, decoration, feathering, etc.), but you need to describe what you're concerned about.  Cutting a region of an image in some way and doing something with the edges covers an endless number of possibilities.  Your question could have a lot of people wasting their time on answers that have nothing to do with what you actually want to know.  In fairness, I'm voting to close until you can clarify.

Comment: Nice term! Clean cut. I made this case simpler and will consider the actual case for future cases.

Comment: To quote from Cool Hand Luke, "What we have here is a failure to communicate." (Might be from before your time.)  The problem is that cutting can describe a lot of things.  You can use it to produce a new image from a piece of an old one, you can use it to create a "window" in the original, you can trim the original, etc.  If the cut is not rectangular, there are a bunch of other considerations, and if you want to do something with the edge there are even more.  Something simple, like cropping or creating a new image, can be done with most image software.  (cont'd)

Comment: A non-rectangular cut, creating a window, or modifying edges might require a more heavy duty application.  The procedure to accomplish whatever it is you want to do will be different in each program.  So without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish and what tools are available to you, it's impossible to answer your question (other than to guess).  So your question could waste a lot of people's time unless, like this case, the first person to guess got lucky.  It also means that your question isn't useful to others because people with a similar problem wouldn't find a solution.

Comment: Therefore, I narrowed the question. I normally use Matlab to do smarter handling of edges. However, it would be great to have some other benchmark too for standard non-clean cutting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cut a region` = Crop, using GIMP, www.gimp.org

1. Select the crop tool
2. Frame the portion you wish to keep
3. Press ENTER
4. Export (File menu) as TIFF

A video on the cropping, plus a resize
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rGGpOTSpbc